# How to delete all cookies in PHP?

Tags: php, cookies

```
setcookie('id', null, 1, "/", ".domain.name");
```

The above will only delete a specific cookie, but how to delete them all?

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310558/how-to-delete-all-cookies-of-my-website-in-php/2310591#2310591

Answer (score 13):

This should do the trick:

```
foreach ($_COOKIES as $c_id => $c_value)
{
    setcookie($c_id, NULL, 1, "/", ".domain.name");
}
```

Comment: Don't know how exactly you expect to set a multi-dimensional array cookie unless the id is like `test[something]`

Comment: well, yeah, since it's referring the name of the cookie, so whatever type the cookie is, it'll be cleared.

Comment: Generally this is correct, but there is an error in your answer - it should be $_COOKIE, not $_COOKIES

Answer (score 0):

```
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE']))
    {
        $cookies = explode(';', $_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE']);
        foreach ($cookies as $cookie)
        {
            $parts = explode('=', $cookie);
            $name = trim($parts[0]);
            setcookie($name, '', time() - 1000);
            setcookie($name, '', time() - 1000, '/');
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -11):

Man, isn't it easier to just wipe out all cookies like this:

```
$_COOKIE=array();
```