# Deleting session cookies with PHP

Tags: php, session, cookies

This is what I need to be doing:
delete all session cookies and destroy the session on the server.
delete the session cookie from the browser.

```
<?php
session_start();
$name = session_name();
$expire = strtotime('-1 year');
$params = session_get_cookie_params();
$path = $params['path'];
$domain = $params['domain'];
$secure = $params['secure'];
$httponly = $params['httponly'];
setcookie($name, '', $expire, $path, $domain, $secure, $httponly);
unset($_SESSION["course_code"]);
unset($_SESSION["course_name"]);
unset($_SESSION["publisher"]);
session_unset();
session_destroy();

?>
```

Does this properly do what needs to be done?

Comment: If you want to unset all of the values, you can just run a `session_destroy()`. It will unset all the values and destroy the session.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to delete all cookies of my website in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310558/how-to-delete-all-cookies-of-my-website-in-php)

Comment: But the `$_SESSION` array will still work in the same page after `session_destroy()`. Then you can simply run `$_SESSION = array()` to reset it's contents.

Comment: Possible duplicate remove request - it doesn't include session destroying, only cookies. Here author asked for sessions & cookies

Comment: @Phiter : As the answer below correctly cites from the manual, `session_destroy()` does _NOT_ delete the session cookie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go, you need to delete in a loop:

```
//when dealing with session always add session_start() on top
session_start();
//From PHP manual: Unset all of the session variables.
//No need to do in a loop for all $_SESSION[] keys
$_SESSION = array();

//For cookies you do similar, from PHP docs:
//http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php#73484

if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE'])) {
    $cookies = explode(';', $_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE']);
    foreach($cookies as $cookie) {
        $parts = explode('=', $cookie);
        $name = trim($parts[0]);
        setcookie($name, '', time()-1000);
        setcookie($name, '', time()-1000, '/');
    }
}
session_destroy();
```

PS: from PHP manual:

> Only use `session_unset()` for older deprecated code that does not use
>   `$_SESSION`. so don't use that. `session_destroy()` destroys all of the
>   data associated with the current session. It does not unset any of the
>   global variables associated with the session, or unset the session
>   cookie.

To be safe call `session_​regenerate_​id()` upon login, logout, and sensitive areas of the script.

Comment: looping is not necessary, you can just use unset($_SESSION);

Comment: just add session_start() on the top, and add my code, nothing else

Comment: You'd need session_start(), other than that, like Phiter said, session_destroy() does all this for you.

Comment: Okay so I just need session_start() and session_destroy() or do I need more?

Comment: cookies you need to do in a loop

Comment: @Muhammed Okay so use all of your code and session_destroy() ?