# Find out what paths a cookie is set for

Tags: php, cookies

I am having some cookie issues.
Things were working fine, and then we did a website update, I enabled security on the cookies, and now the remember me cookie doesn't work any more.

I'm not sure if I have some cookies that are being set in one level and not another, and I wanted to clear all my cookies to start out fresh.

Here's my clear script: (based on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2310591/356438)

```
<pre>
<?
    echo "Before \n\n";
    print_r(explode(";",$_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE']));
    // unset cookies
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE'])) {
        $cookies = explode(';', $_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE']);
        foreach($cookies as $cookie) {
            $parts = explode('=', $cookie);
            $name = trim($parts[0]);
            setcookie($name, '', 1);
            setcookie($name, '', 1, '/');
        }
    }
    echo "\n\n After \n\n";
    print_r(explode(";",$_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE']));
?>
</pre>
```

When I run it on the site root I get this output:

```
Before 

Array
(
    [0] => Test=test
    [1] =>  Test2=test2
    [2] =>  lastvisit=1468329822
    [3] =>  lastvisit=1472134053
    [4] =>  __utma=210079566.190815705.1466193830.1472067428.1472133823.168
    [5] =>  __utmc=210079566
    [6] =>  __utmz=210079566.1469538895.71.3.utmcsr=website.com|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/
    [7] =>  logname=AndyD273
    [8] =>  logid=8d3f09f7fc83eb0592f3d24d332ca85d
)


 After 

Array
(
    [0] => Test=test
    [1] =>  Test2=test2
    [2] =>  lastvisit=1468329822
    [3] =>  lastvisit=1472134053
    [4] =>  __utma=210079566.190815705.1466193830.1472067428.1472133823.168
    [5] =>  __utmc=210079566
    [6] =>  __utmz=210079566.1469538895.71.3.utmcsr=website.com|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/
    [7] =>  logname=AndyD273
    [8] =>  logid=8d3f09f7fc83eb0592f3d24d332ca85d
)
```

And when it run it in the directory with the members area I get this:

```
Before 

Array
(
    [0] => lastvisit=1466790329
    [1] =>  Test=test
    [2] =>  Test2=test2
    [3] =>  lastvisit=1468329822
    [4] =>  lastvisit=1472134053
    [5] =>  __utma=210079566.190815705.1466193830.1472067428.1472133823.168
    [6] =>  __utmc=210079566
    [7] =>  __utmz=210079566.1469538895.71.3.utmcsr=website.com|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/
    [8] =>  logname=AndyD273
    [9] =>  logid=8d3f09f7fc83eb0592f3d24d332ca85d
)


After 

Array
(
    [0] => lastvisit=1466790329
    [1] =>  Test=test
    [2] =>  Test2=test2
    [3] =>  lastvisit=1468329822
    [4] =>  lastvisit=1472134053
    [5] =>  __utma=210079566.190815705.1466193830.1472067428.1472133823.168
    [6] =>  __utmc=210079566
    [7] =>  __utmz=210079566.1469538895.71.3.utmcsr=website.com|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/
    [8] =>  logname=AndyD273
    [9] =>  logid=8d3f09f7fc83eb0592f3d24d332ca85d
)
```

I am setting the cookies with this, in case this isn't the right way to do it:

```
<?
setcookie("logname", $username, time()+(60*60*24*100), "/", ".website.com", true, true);
?>
```

I would love to have a way to see all the cookies and what paths they are being set at so I can make sure I'm doing it right.

**Edit:**

I added the domain section:

setcookie($name, '', 1, '/', '.website.com');

and cleared it down to this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => lastvisit=1466790329
    [1] =>  Test=test
    [2] =>  Test2=test2
    [3] =>  lastvisit=1468329822
)
```

**Edit 2:**
Security certificates seem to be in order
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after looking up the https certificate info, I remembered that Chrome lists all the cookies, including the path and domain info and that helped me figure out what I had done wrong.

Fixed the mistake, cleared out the bad cookies, and now everything is working right.

Helps to get the most accurate info.