# How to delete cookies from the browser?

Tags: php, cookies, server-side

How to delete cookies from the browser? Only problem, I need it to be done from server-side. With that I meant: When user opens page, server automatically deletes cookies that are related to its page. Is that possible? I need it because sometimes users are too, lets say, lazy to do it by themselfs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there sure is a way:

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['cookie']))
{
    //set the expiration date an hour ago
    setcookie ('cookie', '', time() - 3600);
}
```

But then, you have to remember the state, that you already have deleted the cookies for that user and that session, otherwise it will be a headache to set new cookies ;)

**EDIT**: And this also may be useful in your case: [How to delete all cookies in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911801/how-to-delete-all-cookies-in-php)

Comment: Thanks for the link. All genial is simple... `$_COOKIES = array();`.

Answer (score 0):

set the cookie expiration value to a negative value, via your server-side scripting language

for php:

> setcookie('cookie_name','',-1);

Answer (score 0):

```
setcookie("Cookie Name","",time()-3600*24,"/");
```